# Calling controller method in integration test Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

How can i call a specific method from controller in integration tests. For example i have following lines in test/controller/testing.rb file
which is running fine

```
 get :show, {employee_id: @employee.id}
    assert_response :success
```

But how can i call show method in integration test file ?

Comment: Why do you need to use an integration test to directly hit a controller action? What are you trying to test that can't be accomplished from the controller test you've provided above?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller tests, the test knows by convention that when you call `get :show`, it should use the `show` action of the controller with the same name than your test class.

In integration testing, you can't do that. You must use the routes of your application in order to ask for a controller action. The documentation says that you can use `get_via_redirect(path, [parameters], [headers])`, as well as some other methods (see the documentation link below).

The `path` argument of the method can be one of your path helpers (Example for the action `user#show`, use the path helper `user_path(@user)`).

Documentation :

- Integration testing : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing
- Path helpers : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers